# Complex git workflow

Tags: git

I have a scenario in which I have to maintain multiple git repositories  (each with multiple branches) on multiple servers that are not connected together (and never will be).

To simplify the idea, I will identify two hosts as A and B.
Work is performed on A by developers. They are pushing code, making branches, etc.
Work is performed on B by developers. They are pushing code, making branches, etc.

Originally, B is mirrored from A.  So they started identically.

Now I am tasked with taking code from A and bringing it to B.
Likewise, from B and taking it to A.  This will occur on a continual basis.

I am not sure idea how to accomplish this given the fact that:

- When I am on A's network I cannot access B.
- When I am on B's network I cannot access A.
- Developers will be creating new branches on both A and B
- Developers will be pushing code into the same named branches on both A and B.
- Plus many other scenarios I can't even think of :(

  - Maybe implement a PR - but doesn't get merged (on both A and B) when we need to "sync up"

Basically, I am tasked with two teams of developers developing on the same repo that exists on two different networks and 'sneaker netting' the differences between them on an ongoing basis.

Originally I looked into `git clone --mirror` (and `git lfs fetch -all` since LFS is in play), and then `git push --mirror`. This worked fine for the initial sync.  But it cant work for maintenance.

I realize this will ultimately be done programmatically (which is fine), but I am not even sure what process flow I should take on something like this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This seems like a recipe for disaster. Inevitably you will run into conflicts when trying to apply B's changes into A's repository, and will need B's developers to fix it (or do it yourself, which would probably be insufferable if you're not actively involved in the changes). You could force them to take turns merging thinks, but that'd be a terrible experience for the developers too. Is this policy even reasonable?

Comment: How do you switch from "network A" to "network B" ? can you do it from the same machine (e.g : connect to WPN A / connect to VPN B), or is it physically impossible to have a machine which can connect to both networks ?

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino Agreed It's a recipe for disaster.  The person (me or someone else) does does the merging.. will have to deal with it.  I have no idea how that is plausible.

Comment: @LeGEC Both are physically isolated.  I have to bring a laptop from site A to B and vice versa to get code.

Comment: fwiw : I feel for you

Comment: Would it be an interesting starting point to have a procedure to publish code from `site B` to `site A` (and vice versa) ? Say have a set of branches named `siteB/*` on `siteA`, and a set of branches named `siteA/*` on `site B` ? You could then choose a procedure to merge the code in a second step.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a scenario that can be solved with [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).

> Some workflows require that one or more branches of development on one
> machine be replicated on another machine, but the two machines cannot
> be directly connected, and therefore the interactive Git protocols
> (git, ssh, http) cannot be used.

You obviously need to set some rules (like limiting history rewriting), in any case you can check if you can apply the bundle using `git bundle verify`.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing some reading.  Appreciate the tip.